# Should I be using CSS or JS to make my container slide to the right + fade in at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this little UI I'm working on and I'm just now applying some animation to it so it can be activated via keypress in-game. I've sort of got both animations I want, I just can't get them working together, at the same time.

I'm not really familiar with CSS animations, If I could just do this all with after effects, I'd be dandy, but nevertheless.

I have created this image to sort of provide a brief explanation of what I'm looking for and I've got a JSFiddle with the slideout code, plus I'll include a snippet for the fade-in code.

**Brief Explanation of What I'm Looking For:**
[image]

**[Here is the JSFiddle for the slideout animation](https://jsfiddle.net/j365ro1z/)**

**[Here is the JSFiddle with additions made since posting](https://jsfiddle.net/j365ro1z/2/)**

**Below is the Snippet for the FadeIn Animation**

```css
.positive {
    color: rgb(114, 204, 114);
}

.negative {
    color: rgb(224, 50, 50);
}

.tempbg {
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

.portrait {
    background-image: url("https://gdurl.com/VKq8");
    position: fixed;
    top: 34px;
    left: 560px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 110px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

.container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.288);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 660px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 85px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0%;
    z-index: 1;
}

/*#heal, #armor, #hunger, #thirst, #stamina, #voice {
    
}*/

#boxHeal, #boxArmor, #boxStamina, #boxHunger, #boxThirst, #boxVoice {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#heal {
    position: absolute;
    left: 26px;
    bottom: 70px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

#armor {
    position: absolute;
    left: 27px;
    bottom: 54px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 10px;
}

#hunger {
    position: absolute;
    left: 62px;
    bottom: 28px;
    width: 113px;
    height: 10px;
}

.iconhunger {
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
    align-content: left;
 }

#thirst {
    position: absolute;
    left: 22px;
    bottom: 54px;
    width: 113px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

.iconthirst {
    position: relative;
    left: 0.5px;
    bottom: -29.5px;
    z-index: 3;
    align-content: left;
 }

#stamina {
    position: absolute;
    left: 62.5px;
    bottom: 1px;
    width: 113px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

.iconstamina {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    align-content: left;
    left: -36px;
    bottom: -3px;
 }

#voice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    bottom: -00px;
    width: 107.5px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

.fa-microphone {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 69px;
    bottom: 25px;
    color: #525151;
    font-size: 38px;
 }

.fa-microphonebg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 140px;
    width: 121px;
    height: 85px;
    background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px, #fff 51px);
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#boxHeal {
    background: rgb(97, 191, 92);
    border: solid 0.3px rgb(97, 191, 92);
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#boxArmor {
    background: rgb(96, 136, 220);
    border: solid 0.3px rgb(96, 136, 220);
    border-radius: 180px;
    border: -5px;
}

#boxHunger {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    bottom: 7px;
    border: solid 0.3px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#boxThirst {
    background:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: -34px;
    border: solid 0.3px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 30px;

}

#boxStamina {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    bottom: 4px;
    border: solid 0.3px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#boxVoice {
    background: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    height: 27px;
    width: 14.1px;
    left: 215px;
    bottom: 36.5px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#boxVoice.active {
    background: rgb(46, 196, 66);
}

.position {
    font-family: "gta-ui", Verdana, Tahoma;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.35%;
    left: 16%;
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 2px #000, 1px 1px 2px #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.seperator {
    color: rgb(224, 50, 50);
}

.seperator2 {
    color: rgb(240, 200, 80);
}

#slideout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: -25px;
    animation-delay: : 2s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
  
#slideout_tab {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
  
#slideout_inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 26px;
}
  
#showblock:not(:checked)+#slideout {
    left: -195px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

#showblock:checked+#slideout {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInFromNone 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: fadeInFromNone 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-animation: fadeInFromNone 0.5s ease-out;
    animation: fadeInFromNone 0.5s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    0% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    1% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    0% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    1% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    0% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    1% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    0% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    1% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
  
  #showblock {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>SoL RP UI</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://icono-49d6.kxcdn.com/icono.min.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3f31cfc768.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="tempbg">
    <div class="portrait">
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showblock">
        <div id="slideout">

        <label id="slideout_tab" for="showblock" title="Admin Slider">
        </label>

        <div id="slideout_inner">
        <div class="container">

            <div id="heal">
                <div id="boxHeal"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="armor">
                <div id="boxArmor"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="hunger">
                <svg class="iconhunger" width="36" height="12" viewBox="0 0 14 12" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
                        <path d="M9.44096 7.09788L12.0944 4.62314C13.9855 2.86906 14.0734 1.25095 13.9708 0.462298C13.9561 0.407908 13.9268 0.353518 13.8828 0.312725C13.7656 0.203945 13.5897 0.203945 13.4724 0.312725L12.6954 1.03339L2.94672 10.0893C2.62421 10.3885 2.62421 10.8916 2.94672 11.1907C3.26923 11.4899 3.81164 11.4899 4.13415 11.1907L4.33939 10.946C4.70588 10.4973 6.58232 7.98172 6.86086 7.58739C6.97813 7.42422 7.09541 7.32904 7.18337 7.28825C7.32997 7.23386 7.44724 7.30185 7.44724 7.30185C8.09227 7.65538 8.91321 7.58739 9.44096 7.09788Z" fill="white"/>
                        <path d="M4.95508 6.20047C5.49749 5.9965 5.86398 6.17327 6.09854 6.36364L6.86084 5.65657C6.65561 5.43901 6.46503 5.08547 6.68493 4.59596C6.99278 3.90249 7.242 3.45377 6.17184 2.37957C5.131 1.29176 3.4598 0.285548 2.68283 0.0679876C2.50692 0.027195 2.331 0 2.19906 0C2.1844 0 2.1844 0 2.16974 0C2.12577 0 2.09645 0.0135975 2.06713 0.0407925C1.99383 0.10878 1.99383 0.21756 2.06713 0.27195L4.70587 2.7195C4.83781 2.84188 4.83781 3.04584 4.70587 3.18182C4.57393 3.3042 4.35404 3.3042 4.20744 3.18182L3.89959 2.89627L3.21058 2.25719C2.69749 1.78127 2.36032 1.46853 2.03781 1.22378C1.26084 0.625486 0.95299 0.611888 0.95299 0.611888C0.95299 0.611888 0.835713 0.598291 0.733095 0.679876C0.645137 0.775058 0.659797 0.883838 0.659797 0.883838C0.659797 0.883838 0.674456 1.16939 1.33414 1.90365C1.59802 2.2028 1.93519 2.51554 2.44828 2.99145L3.13728 3.63054L3.44514 3.91608C3.57707 4.03846 3.57707 4.24242 3.44514 4.3784C3.3132 4.50078 3.0933 4.50078 2.94671 4.3784L0.307964 1.93085C0.234666 1.86286 0.117388 1.86286 0.0587496 1.93085C0.0294302 1.95804 0.0147705 1.98524 0.0147705 2.02603C0.0147705 2.02603 0.0147705 2.03963 0.0147705 2.05322C0.0147705 2.1756 0.0440899 2.33877 0.0880689 2.50194C0.307964 3.22261 1.40744 4.75913 2.58022 5.75175C3.73833 6.71717 4.20744 6.48601 4.95508 6.20047Z" fill="white"/>
                        <path d="M9.51434 7.737C9.1625 7.95456 8.73737 8.07694 8.29758 8.07694C8.03371 8.07694 7.78449 8.03614 7.53528 7.95456L10.6138 11.3539C11.0683 11.7619 11.7866 11.7619 12.2264 11.3539C12.6662 10.946 12.6662 10.2661 12.2264 9.85821L9.51434 7.737Z" fill="white"/>
                        </g>
                </svg> 
                <div id="boxHunger">                           
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="thirst">
                <svg class="iconthirst" width="36" height="14" viewBox="0 0 8 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M3.74196 0.100677C3.72525 0.0356591 3.65843 -0.013104 3.57491 0.00315034C3.52479 0.0194047 3.49138 0.0519134 3.47467 0.100677C2.9067 4.55437 0 5.46462 0 8.5692C0.0501155 10.5035 1.68722 12.0476 3.67514 11.9989C5.61294 11.9664 7.16652 10.4385 7.19993 8.5692C7.21663 5.48087 4.30993 4.55437 3.74196 0.100677ZM3.19069 5.02575C3.15728 5.15579 3.10716 5.30207 3.07375 5.44836C2.82317 6.34235 2.52248 7.35013 2.52248 8.52044C2.52248 9.15436 2.13826 9.38192 1.77075 9.38192C1.35312 9.38192 1.01902 9.05683 1.01902 8.65048C1.01902 7.26885 1.70393 6.35861 2.30531 5.56215C2.48907 5.31833 2.67283 5.07451 2.82317 4.84695C2.88999 4.74943 3.00693 4.73317 3.10716 4.79819C3.12387 4.81444 3.14057 4.8307 3.15728 4.84695C3.19069 4.89572 3.20739 4.96073 3.19069 5.02575Z" fill="white"/>
                </svg>
                <div id="boxThirst"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="stamina">
                <svg class="iconstamina" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 487.811 487.81" style="enable-background:new 0 0 487.811 487.81;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <g>
                        <g>
                        <g id="_x33_6_24_">
                        <g>
                        <path d="M150.463,109.521h150.512c3.955,0,7.16-3.206,7.16-7.161c0-3.955-3.205-7.161-7.16-7.161H150.463     c-3.955,0-7.161,3.206-7.161,7.161C143.302,106.315,146.508,109.521,150.463,109.521z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#000000" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <path d="M15.853,179.537h150.511c3.955,0,7.161-3.206,7.161-7.161s-3.206-7.16-7.161-7.16H15.853     c-3.955,0-7.161,3.205-7.161,7.16S11.898,179.537,15.853,179.537z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#000000" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <path d="M56.258,253.214c0,3.955,3.206,7.162,7.161,7.162H213.93c3.955,0,7.161-3.207,7.161-7.162s-3.206-7.16-7.161-7.16H63.419     C59.464,246.054,56.258,249.259,56.258,253.214z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#000000" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <path d="M142.396,336.44H7.161C3.206,336.44,0,339.645,0,343.6s3.206,7.161,7.161,7.161h135.235c3.955,0,7.161-3.206,7.161-7.161     S146.351,336.44,142.396,336.44z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#000000" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <path d="M385.729,154.418c21.6,0,39.111-17.513,39.111-39.114s-17.512-39.113-39.111-39.113     c-21.605,0-39.119,17.513-39.119,39.113C346.609,136.905,364.123,154.418,385.729,154.418z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#000000" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <path d="M450.066,143.155c-22.459,31.459-52.533,35.102-84.895,15.89c-2.203-1.306-11.977-6.691-14.141-7.977     c-52.061-30.906-104.061-18.786-138.934,30.05c-14.819,20.771,19.455,40.459,34.108,19.93     c18.018-25.232,40.929-32.533,65.986-24.541c-12.83,22.27-24.047,44.405-39.875,75.853     c-15.832,31.448-50.787,56.562-84.374,36.92c-24.235-14.165-46.09,20.651-21.928,34.772     c45.854,26.799,99.619,10.343,127.066-24.493c0.952,0.509,1.958,0.968,3.062,1.354c22.422,7.812,51.814,28.61,60.77,35.981     c8.953,7.371,24.336,44.921,33.471,63.788c11.082,22.893,46.871,6.219,35.748-16.771c-10.355-21.406-27.736-64.129-41.293-74.938     c-10.875-8.669-31.988-24.803-49.895-33.956c12.115-23.466,24.729-46.679,38.008-69.491     c42.328,12.969,82.561-2.308,111.215-42.446C498.996,142.312,464.73,122.624,450.066,143.155z" data-original="#000000" class="active-path" data-old_color="#000000" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        </g>
                        </g>
                        </g>
                        </g> 
                </svg>
                <div id="boxStamina"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="voice">
                    <div class="fa-microphonebg">
                    <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
                    </div>                
                    <div id="boxVoice"></div>
            </div>

        </div>   /*container*/
        </div>   /*slideout_inner*/
        </div>   /*slideout*/

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
    </script>

    <script src="js/app.js">
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/astrotim/pen/KDBbe

I found this codepen which sort of has what I'm looking for, slide and fade but I'm not 100% sure if it would work as it fades too slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad, however I think one can sum it up to two methods:

1. Use classes to describe the state of the elements (e.g. the circle in the middle or on the left)
2. Use `transform: translateX()` together with the `transition` property.

For example, in the following snippet the `right` class is toggled upon clicking the red box:

```js
const box = document.getElementById('box');

box.addEventListener('click', () => {
  box.classList.toggle('right');
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(100%); /* When an element has the 'right' class, 
                                  it would move to the right by 100% */
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

You can modify this minimal example and play with the properties that vary among the "states" of your objects: their `width`, `opacity` and - of course - `translate`, as mentioned above.